# How do I upload to Azure Blob storage without overwriting?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

Calling UploadFromStream overwrites files by default - how can I make sure I only upload a blob if it isn't already in the container?

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add an access condition to the code so that it checks against the [ETag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobproperties.etag.aspx) property of the blob - wildcards are allowed, so we want to only allow the upload if no blobs with this name have any etag (which is a roundabout way of saying, does this blob name exist).

You get a StorageException as detailed below.

```
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    try {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream, accessCondition: AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition("*"));
    } catch (StorageException ex) {
        if (ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict) {
            // Handle duplicate blob condition
        }
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with the new `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package?

Answer (score 11):

Azure now has an access condition that will only add, not overwrite: `AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition()`

Definition:

> Constructs an access condition such that an operation will be performed only if the resource does not exist.

Example:

```
var accessCondition = AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition();
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream, accessCondition);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by Rob Church seems ok. Checking strings for errors isn't best practice and be improved with:

```
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        try
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream, accessCondition: AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition("*"));
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            if (ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                // Handle duplicate blob condition
            }
            throw;
        }
```